# In Node.js, Why I cannot reach category' id into nested structure?

Tags: node.js, express, nested, schema, ejs

How can I reach the 2nd and 3rd layer's "id" or "_id"?
Here is my home.ejs

```
<h1> 1. layer "name"= <%- categories[0].name %> ..testing</h1>
<h1> 1. layer "id"  = <%- categories[0]._id %>   ..testing</h1>
<h1> 2. layer "name"= <%- categories[0].categories[0].name %> ..testing</h1>
<h1> 2. layer "id"  = <%- categories[0].categories[0]._id %>      ..testing</h1>
<h1> 3. layer "name"= <%- categories[0].categories[0].categories[0].name %> ..testing</h1>
<h1> 3. layer "id"  = <%- categories[0].categories[0].categories[0]._id %>   ..testing</h1>
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixjMd.png)
As you can see, I can reach the name of nested categories, however, I cannot reach 2nd and 3rd layers "id" or "_id"

[Here is my data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJ5RM.jpg)

Comment: Post your data...

Comment: You have a typo. Shouldn't it be e.x `categories[0].categories[0].id` instead of `categories[0].categories[0]._id`? Note I use `id`, not `_id`

Comment: Hello Subburaj, I posted my data set.

Comment: I also tried with id, however, the result is the same. Still, I cannot reach 2nd or 3rd layer id's.

Comment: Just try with <%- categories[0].categories[0]["id"]%> for 2nd layer id and same pattern for 3rd layer id.

Comment: shiva, I tried. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to debug with console log and check your properties of your JSON objects

```
<h1> 1. layer "id"  = <% console.log(categories[0]) %>..testing</h1>
<h1> 2. layer "name"= <% console.log(categories[0].categories[0]) %> ..testing</h1>
<h1> 3. layer "name"= <% console.log(categories[0].categories[0].categories[0] )%> ..testing</h1>
```